# Spark Broadcasting a HashMap no nullpointer but it doesnt fetch any values aswell

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am broadcasting a hashmap and returning a map from the below method

```
public static Map<Object1, Object2> lkpBC (JavaSparkContext ctx, String FilePath) {
  Broadcast<Map<Object1, Object2>> CodeBC = null;
  Map<Object1, Object2> codePairMap=null;
  try {
    Map<Object1, Object2> CodepairMap = LookupUtil.loadLookup(ctx, FilePath);
    CodeBC = ctx.broadcast(codePairMap);
    codePairMap= CodeBC.value();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.error("Error while broadcasting ", e);
  }

  return codePairMap;
}
```

and passing the map to the below method

```
public static JavaRDD<Object3> fetchDetails(
  JavaSparkContext ctx,
  JavaRDD<Object3> CleanFileRDD,
  String FilePath,
  Map<Object1, Object2> BcMap
) {

  JavaRDD<Object3r> assignCd = CleanFileRDD.map(row -> {
    object3 FileData = null;
    try {
      FileData = row;

      if (BCMap.containsKey("some key")) {......}

    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.error("Error in Map function ", e);
    }

    return some object;
  });

  return assignCd; 
 }
```

in the local mode it works fine without any issues but when i run this on a spark standalone cluster(1 master 3 slaves) on EC2 this doesn't fetch any values nor throws an error. All the objects you see in the methods are serialized. Does it matter if i am calling these methods from a main class or any other different class?

PS: We use Kyro serializer in the spark conf

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a Spark related problem. Has to be a bug in the code somewhere.  I would recommend switching to Scala as all that code would be like 2 lines, not have any mutation, no side effects, etc, and therefore generally easier to reason about.

Comment: Scala isn't an option yet for the platform . Cant say its a bug in the code since it works locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what's going on is you are not accessing the broadcast variable inside the closure of your map function.  I think you are directly accessing the underlying `BcMap` (or `BCMap`, not sure if they are supposed to be different).

Line `if (BCMap.containsKey("some key"))` isn't accessing the broadcast variable `CodeBC`. Since it seems the type of `BCMap` is `Map`, not `Broadcast`.

**To access the broadcast variable you would call `CodeBC.value.containsKey`.**

Spark is designed in a functional way, it doesn't "do" anything to the underlying map, it makes a copy of it, broadcasts the copy, and wraps that copy in a `Broadcast` type.

I don't know what `LookupUtil.loadLookup` does, but I guess if the file doesn't exist or is empty does it return an empty map?

Here is an example of how you would do it in Scala:

```
val bcMap = ctx.broadcast(LookupUtil.loadLookup(ctx, FilePath))

cleanFileRDD.map(row => 
  if (bcMap.value.containsKey("some key") ...
  else ...)
```

I think you will solve your situation by following the wise words of a friend of mine "first solve all the obvious issues, then the harder issues seem to solve themselves".  In your case they are:

1. Using mutable variables that get initialised to null
2. Using try catches that log errors but don't re-throw them. Just let exceptions bubble up.
3. Prematurely splitting things out into lots of different methods before you have it working as just one method.

And just because something works locally doesn't mean it will work when distributed.  There are a lot of differences between running something locally and across a cluster, like: a) Data locality b) Serialization c) Closure capture d) Number of threads e) execution order ... etc

Comment: Great explanation! I missed the fact that spark does not do anything to the underlying map. I was using the ContainsKey on a null map which was not executed/initialized . Thanks once again. what worked for me was in my if condition  **bcMap.value.containsKey("some key")** ...